# how to read a table in a text file column wise in bash

Tags: bash

I am very new to bash scripting and today I have worked on a problem which I generally do  it in python. The problem is I have a text file which is like this: (numbers in the row are separated by tabs)

```
1   1   1   1   1
9   3   4   5   5
6   7   8   9   7
3   6   8   9   1
3   4   2   1   4
6   4   4   7   7
```

Now I have written a bash script which reads row by row and calculates row average and median for the row. Now I want to calculate the column average and column  median. how can I do this I am finding it difficult to read it column wise. **I don't want to use awk** this is my code:

```
#! /bin/bash
clear
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Please provide arguments"
elif [ "$#" -lt 2 ]; then
     echo "You have to provide 2 arguments"
elif [ "$#" -gt 2 ]; then
    echo "You have provided more number of arguments"
else
    echo "You have entered correct number of arguments"
fi
option="${1}" 
case ${option} in 
   -rows| -r) FILE="${2}"
      echo "rows" 
      echo "File name is $FILE"
      clear
      echo "Average Median"
      while read -r line
      do
      len=0
      tot=0
      name=$line
      IFS=' ' read -a array <<< "$name"
      for element in "${array[@]}"
      do
          tot=$(expr $tot + $element)
          #let tot+=$element #you can use this as well to get the totals
          let len+=1
      done
      avg= printf "%.0f" $(echo "scale=2;$tot/$len" | bc)
      readarray -t sorted < <(for a in "${array[@]}"; do echo "$a"; done | sort)
      no=`expr $len % 2`
      if [ $no -eq 0 ]; then
      mid=`expr $len / 2`
      echo "$avg   ${sorted[$mid]}"
      else
      mid=`expr $len / 2`
      echo "$avg   ${sorted[$mid]}"
      fi
      unset "array[@]"
      unset "sorted[@]"
      done < "$FILE"
      ;; 
   -cols| -c) FILE="${2}" 
      echo "cols"
      echo "File name is $FILE"
      while read line
      do
      x=1
      read -a array <<< "$line"
      for element in "${!arra[@]}"
      do
      row[${element}] = $((${row[${element}]}+${array[$element]}))
      ((x++))
      done
      done < "$FILE"
      for element in ${row[@]}
      do
      mean=$(echo "$element/$x" bc -l)
      echo "$element / $x = $mean"
      done
      ;; 
   *)  
      echo "`basename ${0}`:usage: [-r|-rows rows] | [-c|-cols columns]" 
      exit 1 # Command to come out of the program with status 1
      ;; 
esac 

Can anyone help me with this please
```

Comment: You haven't really made an attempt for the columns case. Most of your code is for the rows, so is unrelated to the question. You should try making an attempt for the columns, or at least come up with some ideas about how to go about it and then ask a more specific question, focusing on what you're stuck with.

Comment: yeah I was doing I am getting lot of errors. I will re edit in few mins

Comment: Has this got to be pure bash then, no utilities ?

Comment: except awk I am ok with anything

Comment: What's your problem with awk?! It's basically the right tool for the job. Would you be happy to use perl, for example?

Comment: yeah perl would be fine for me, is it difficult to do in bash I am just in the learning phase so I am very rigid to stick to bash. Sorry for that

Comment: but I don't know perl

Comment: @ayaan I'm just learning too, but awk is much much easier for this type of thing.

Comment: awk is by far the best solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this looks like homework i have only provided code for the mean although the median can be found using pretty much the same method.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line;do
    x=1
    read -a array <<< "$line" ##Split the line by spaces
    for element in "${!array[@]}"
    do
         row[${element}]=$((${row[${element}]}+${array[$element]})) ##For each column increment array variable by number in the column.
         ((x++))
   done
done < test

for element in ${row[@]}
do
    mean=$(echo "$element/$x" | bc -l) ##bc can be omitted if you just want integers
    echo "$element / $x = $mean"
done
```

#### Output

```
28 / 6 = 4.66666666666666666666
25 / 6 = 4.16666666666666666666
27 / 6 = 4.50000000000000000000
32 / 6 = 5.33333333333333333333
25 / 6 = 4.16666666666666666666
```

Same thing in awk(which would be the preferred solution.)

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[i]+=$i}END{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print a[i]/NR}' test
```

Comment: i used your code i am not getting the output onto the console, can you tell me where I have written wrong. I redited the code I posted. please clarify this

Comment: How could i possibly know what you have written wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to get the average with bash than to get the median. Maybe something like this:

```
for ((i=1;i<=$(head -1 test.txt | wc -w);i++)) do
  echo "$(echo $(($(cut -f${i} test.txt | tr "\n" "+" )0)))/$(wc -l < test.txt)" | bc -l
done
```

Here's an example I found for finding the median with bash:
https://cs.fit.edu/~mmahoney/cse4001/median.bash.txt

> This program computes the median of a list of integers on the command
>   line. If there are no arguments, then it asks the user to enter them
>   on separate lines.  Then it prints the median (middle value after
>   sorting).  If there are an even number of numbers, then the median is
>   the average of the 2 middle values, rounding down

There are some other, shorter examples if you search where you can easily loop through the columns using the same `cut` method above.

Comment: it showing an error in the "sum line" this is the error: /exp.sh: line 5: 1     1       1       1       1+9     3       4       5       5+6     7       8       9       7+3     6       8       9       1+3     4       2       1       4+6     4       4       7       7+ 0 : syntax error in expression (error token is "1 1       1       1+9     3       4       5       5+6     7       8       9       7+3     6       8       9       1+3     4       2       1       4+6     4       4       7       7+ 0 ")
(standard_in) 1: syntax error

Comment: oh, I think the `cut -d` delimiter is wrong... are those spaces between your columns or tabs? ... nevermind I just re-read the first part of your question

Comment: Hmm, so I learned that tab is default. Good to know. (Edited)

Comment: i liked your code but the problem is x may not be 5 everytime, I want to write a generic code